# python all() iterate through a string

Tags: python, string, loops

I would like to iterate through a string and make sure that the string only consists of these letters: 'A','C','G','T'

```
>>>string = 'm'
>>>nucleotide = ('A','C','G','T')
>>>print(all(nucleotide for i in string))
```

This is what I entered, but it comes out to be true in the output. Why is that?

Answer (score 4):

You are testing if `nucleotide` is not empty; you never test `i` against it.

You'd have to use `in` to actually see if `i` is in the tuple:

```
all(i in nucleotide for i in string)
```

It'd be more efficient to make `nucleotide` a set:

```
nucleotide = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'}
```

More efficient still is to use a regular expression, at which point the whole test is done in C code:

```
import re

dna_bases = re.compile(r'^[ACGT]+$')

print(dna_bases.fullmatch(string) is not None)  # Python 3.4, use .match for earlier versions.
```

Comment: Why use `re.search` and an anchored regex when you could just use `re.match` instead? `search` tries to match the regex at every position in the string, which is completely pointless in this case. And upwards of python 3.4 you can also drop the `$` anchor and just use `re.fullmatch`.

Comment: @Rawing: I prefer to use an explicit anchor (`^`)  over `re.match()`. I wasn't aware of `re.fullmatch()`, that one at least is more helpful than `re.match()` implicit `^` anchor.

Comment: Well, you can still use an explicit anchor with `re.match`. It's about efficiency - `re.search` scans through the entire string, which is pointless since the regex is anchored to the start and won't match anywhere else. On my PC, `re.search` is slower by a factor of 100 when used on a 500-character string. IMO using `re.match` also makes it clearer that you're validating the string, not searching for something in it.

Comment: @Rawing: Bah, you are indeed correct. I made the assumption that the `^` anchor (or `\A`, for that matter), would be the only difference, but for invalid input, `re.search()` is indeed a lot slower.